# What is the best practice for dynamically loading <script> and CSS Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

Good Morning! from indonesia, well I need to dynamically load different CSS and Javascript for different component for instance i have slideshow component then i need to load js and css files related to it, and i have form component, i need to load the related css and jss files as well.

What's the proper way or best practice to do its in react.js? Thank you.

Comment: You could look at  webpack, system.js, jspm.io...  These are all module loaders, and should all work with reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about needing them when you build your app, You can do this by using a build tool called webpack.  It will look though your code and bundle all required files into a new folder for you.  You simply require/import the related files in your component js.

[here's](https://github.com/AriaFallah/WebpackTutorial/tree/master/part1) a good tutorial for you.

if you're talking about dynamically loading the styles and scripts as the slideshow component is loaded, you can simply include a

```
<script> and or <link>
```

in your render method.

Note that a react component is not supposed to alter the DOM directly. Therefore, if you have a js slideshow widget that you want to "componentify", you may run into issues.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.  don't forget to choose the best answer and upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

My answer should be read with a grain of salt in that it's an opinionated answer to a broad question that you posed.

IMO, a good and modern way to dynamically load css+javascript+html bits as and when needed is to use react alongside [WebComponents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).  Have a look at [WebComponents section on react's website](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/web-components.html) and pay close attention to the issues that may arise in using [WebComponents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).

Here is a starting example: [WebComponent + React Example](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/examples/webcomponents/index.html)